# How to use different error codes for validation messages?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I have a Spring Boot REST server which should return specific error codes when invalid input is provided. I don't need any i18n here, just plain English error codes like 'missing' is sufficient.

Using Spring Boot with Hibernate Validator, after validation I get a back Spring `Errors` object.

For each error I can get the `code` and `defaultMessage`. For a @NotBlank constraint this would return `NotBlank` and `may not be null` resp.

Basically I want to translate this error to just `missing` as I'm not interested in i18n translation. Also other constraints I want to more REST friendly error codes.

I though to use use a simple `messages.properties` or `ValidationMessages.properties` inside `src/main/resources` but this wouldn't work unfortunately. Note I tried both adding a general `NotBlank=missing` and specific `NotBlank.entity.field=missing` properties.

I'm not sure why it's not working... maybe because resolving i18n messages (in jsp world) does not go directly via Spring `Errors` but through the `MessageCodesResolver` implementation (just guessing).

Probably I could get the error code from the Spring `Error` and do a lookup from the message code resolver.
But I wonder why `error.getDefaultMessage` does not return the appropriate value form the `ValidationMessages.properties`.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Because `error.getDefaultMessage` gets the default message and that is the message as generated by code not from properties files. If you look at the [`MessageSource.getMessage`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html#getMessage-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) method you see that the `defaultMessage` is passed in. The same mechanism is used when using validation.

Comment: Thx for explanation! What would you suggest to go forward?

Comment: You can just pass the error (as is) to the `MessageSource` the errors as returned from the `Errors` object are all instances of `MessageSourceResolvable`. So just iterate over the errors, pass them to the `MessageSource` and get the message you want from the `messages.properties`. Maybe you could gentrify this logic and put it in a class that generates a response object.

Comment: Yes as I suggested myself. Thx!

Comment: Well you suggested to use the code, you don't have to do that, just pass the object as is.

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default message is the message as stated by the programmer. In the case of those JSR-303 annotations probably the ones as Hibernate thought of them. The default message including the code is passed to the [`MessageSource.getMessage`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html#getMessage-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) method, which contains a parameter `defaultMessage`

When you look at the `Errors` object or actually the `ObjectError` method you will see that it implements the `MessageSourceResolvable` interface. This means you can just pass the error, as is, to the `MessageSource`, including the `Locale` if you want.

```
@RequestMapping
public Object foo(@Valid @RequestBody MyObject obj, Errors errors, Locale locale) {
    for (ObjectError err : errors.getAllErrors()) {
        String msg = messageSource.getMessage(err, locale);
        // Do something with msg
    }
}
```

Something like the above should resolve the message. The advantage of using the `ObjectError` itself is that next to the code you also have the parameters (for `@Range` or `@Min`) which you can then use in your message with placeholders.

Comment: Ps hibernate validator default messages should be overridden via ValidationMessages.properties but seems not to work (within Spring app at least). See also https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html

Comment: Correct because that overrides that mechanism so that a `MessageSource` can be used. The `ValidationMessages.properties` apply in a plain JSR-303. This is explained in the [`LocalValidatorFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html) javadoc.

Comment: Hmm would it be possible to change this behavior in Spring? So to use ValidationMessages.properties?

Comment: Are we able to auto resolve the error message without injecting `message source` and `locale` in every of the controllers? This is really troublesome, because I can do it in hibernate annotation but why Spring validator is not working.